# visual studio express: when i add a reference it copies the unit into my project, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What I want is for my projects to refer to a common unit... but every time I add a reference to the unit in a project that does not currently use the unit, vs express makes a copy...

How to solve without the copy issue?

Answer (score 0):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
>
> To set the Copy Local property to False
>
> - In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.
> - In the Project Designer, select the References tab.
> - Select a referenced component in the References list
> - The properties associated with that reference appear in a list in the Properties window.
> - Select Copy Local from the left-hand column, and then click the arrow in the right-hand column to change the value to False.

Comment: Ummm, in VS2010, I don't see how to add a cs file in the "references" branch of the solution explorer. Rather, I right click on the project and choose Add, find the .cs file, and it gets copied into the project. I want to share this unit across projects.... how?